# How to share with others a poll's result as a chart?

Tags: google-forms, google-sheets-charts

I've created a form on Google Drive. The form is public, anyone can see it and respond to it. I would like also to provide a link to the data gathered by the form, however I would like to provide the link which displays the data as a chart. But I do not know how to do this.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiKpG-WK821wdHNQTmJSZGFmOFY4bnFESE50QThIN1E) is the data for the link.

What else should I do to display it as a chart for anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of question, Google Forms could create a chart automatically for you and display it in the "Summary of responses".

From [View and manage form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)

> #### View the summary of responses
>
> To quickly see how many users filled out a form and what their
>   responses are, you can check out the response summary. From your form,
>   click the **Responses** menu and select **Summary of responses**.
>
> If you'd like respondents to be able to see this same summary of
>   responses, check the box in the "Confirmation page" section of your
>   form labeled **Publish and show a link to the results of this form**. When
>   this box is checked, users who respond to your form will see a “See
>   previous results” link, which they can click to view the response
>   summary.

The alternative is to create your own chart and publish it.

1. Create a chart
2. Publish the chart as a web page
3. Share the web page

---

**References**

- [Create a chart or graph](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63728?hl=en)
- [Publishing a chart to a webpage or blog post](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78052?hl=en)